# PopBackStack is not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have coded like this:

FragA >> FragB >> FragC >> FragD

When I press onBackpress() of FragD it goes to directly on FragA but i want to keep it go FragC.

BackPress Code here :

```
 if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            back_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
```

Replacing Fragment Code :

```
                       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                       FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
                       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayoutinner, fragmentA);
                       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentA");
                       fragmentTransaction.commit();



                       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                       FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                       FragmentA fragmentB = new Fragmentb();
                       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayoutinner_2, fragmentB);
                       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentB");
                       fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: have you used addtobackstack method when you are doing fragment transaction?

Comment: If you you are adding the fragment transactions to the Backstack, there is no need of handling the Backstack in `onBackPressed()`. It will be taken care by the Activity hosting the fragments.

Comment: Are you using two containers? framelayoutinner and framelayoutinner_2

Comment: Would be helpful if you add the xml layout as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using nested fragments, if you load fragment from another fragment then it become nested structure. So try to check if any child fragment exist within your Root fragment then pop that child fragment first.

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` for that and make recursive calls till you get most young child fragment(Last added). Or better use **Tag** on your fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add every fragment into backstack using addToBackStack method

```
  public void setmFragmentContainer(Fragment fragment)
    {
        final String tag = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.layout_content, fragment, tag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

This method may help you

Comment: It's not declared in question that he is not adding fragments to backstack

Comment: Yes I have added it to  back stack.

Comment: Yes you are right Umar but addTobackstack will help him to maintain backstack of fragments in fragmentmanager

Comment: @Reena Which code of lines you want .... while replacing fragments or while backpress ?

Comment: Replacing fragments

Comment: @ManojSrivastava put all the code you are using to navigate between fragments

Comment: Are you using two containers? framelayoutinner and framelayoutinner_2,

Comment: @Reena I am using Framelayout

Comment: Yes but are these two framelayouts? As i see in your code you are adding FragA to framelayoutinner and FragB to framelayoutinner_2

Comment: No @Reena only one Framelayout. But scenario is one framelayout is in Activity and other one is in Fragment.

Comment: if you are replacing fragment inside fragment then you need to implement childfragment manager and its callback of onbackpressed too